# Using Approval and Disapproval for Device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stackmob

I am fetching record from database and printing it on table. 
See the Image:
[image]

For Device-permission column I want to use Button which will show Disapproved (means device is approved )if value is "true" and OnClick on the button i want to call a function which will update the value "false " against the IMEI in to database (means now the device become disappoved to use ).. In the same way if the value is **false** I want to show a button which will display Approve means on click of it I want to call a function to update the value **true** at the place of **false**  against that IMEI in database . The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * This code declares your class and saves an object "blogentry" to the table on StackMob.
 * StackMob will create the table for you automatically based on your JSON.
 */
 $(document).ready(function() {
            result();
            function result() {

            var device = StackMob.Model.extend({ schemaName: 'device' });
            var mydevice = new device({ });
                    var q = new StackMob.Collection.Query();
                    q.equals('device_org', 1);
                    q.setRange(0,9).orderDesc('lastmoddate');

                    mydevice.query(q, {
                        success: function(modal) {
                            //After StackMob returns "Bill Watterson", print out the result
                            var array = modal.toJSON();
                             // console.debug(array);
                             //$('#data').html(array[0].user_name);
                             var val = array[0].lastmoddate;
                             $('#last_mod_date').attr('value', val);


                                var key;
                                var count = 0;
                                for(key in array) {
                                     if(array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                      count ++;
                                     }
                                 }
                                 //alert(count);
                            for(var i=0; i<=count; i++)
                            {

                            //  if(array[i].org_img == localStorage.getItem("stackmob.oauth2.user"))

                                //alert(array[i].org_img);
                                    //$('#last_mod_date').html(array[0].lastmoddate);

                                    //alert(val);
                                    $("#ui").append("<tr><td>"+array[i].device_IMEI+"</td><td>"+array[i].device_model+"</td><td>"+array[i].device_permission+"</td><td>"+array[i].device_nickname+"</td><td>"+ new Date(array[i].lastmoddate)+"</td><tr>");

                                 //end if condition
                            } // end for loop
                        } //end success
                     }); // end imagesearch schema query
                     } // end result function

            setInterval(check_newentry,1000);

                     function check_newentry() {
                        var device = StackMob.Model.extend({ schemaName: 'device' });
            var mydevice = new device({  });
                    var q = new StackMob.Collection.Query();
                    q.orderDesc('lastmoddate');
                    mydevice.query(q, {
                        success: function(modal) {
                            //After StackMob returns "Bill Watterson", print out the result
                            var array = modal.toJSON();
                             // console.debug(array);
                             //$('#data').html(array[0].user_name);


                            // alert(lastmod_date_old +"..."+ lastmod_date);
                             if(lastmod_date_old < lastmod_date)
                            {

                                var val = array[0].lastmoddate;
                                 $('#last_mod_date').attr('value', val);

                                var key;
                                var count = 0;
                                var counter=0;
                                for(key in array) {
                                     if(array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                      count ++;
                                     }
                                 }
                                 //alert(count);
                         for(var i=0; i<=count; i++)
                            {

                                if(counter<50)
                                {

                                    $("#ui").append("<tr><td>"+array[i].device_IMEI+"</td><td>"+array[i].device_model+"</td><td>"+array[i].device_permission+"</td><td></td>"+array[i].device_nickname+"<td>"+new Date(array[i].lastmoddate)+"</td><tr>");

                                    //------------------------------------------- end device schema code
                                    counter++;

                                }
                                else
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                        }
                     });
                     } // end check_newentry 
                     });



        </script>
```

So my question is:
1.How can i put the button with above described state.
2.How can i call a function when the "approved/disapproved button" is clicked and how can i access only that row value where Button got clicked..Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this for multiple rows or just one at a time?

Comment: Just One at a time.. i mean after i want to call a function which will update against only one imei based on which row is clicked..